# Caching in Azure

Tags: java, azure, caching

I am new to Azure and exploring cache related services in Azure. I see only Azure cache for redis service as PAAS offering. What if I use memcached or hazelcast in my on-prem and want to move app to Azure? Do we use same service or we need create VM and install all these(IAAS)? I am looking for PAAS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Cache is a PaaS offering which comes with an SLA which covers the connectivity to the cache endpoints. If you want to go for a VM based option you need to handle the updates etc.

Comment: You might also want to consider Azure Table Storage for caching it has near single digit ms response times and is significantly cheaper than Redis cache but you obviously have to write more code in the app as you don't get things like expiry rules and subscribing to changes but it can be very cost effective and performant